# String to String Array each 'n' characters

Tags: c#, split

I have a string builder which contains 5000 characters. I need to split it, to 5 strings which they will contain 1000 characters each.
Is there any method i can use?

Comment: There is [StringBuilder.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Text_StringBuilder_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: Thank you can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop 1000 at a time, and use `ToString` to get the substring:

```cs
const int chunkSize = 1000;
var newStrings = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < myStringBuilder.Length; i += chunkSize)
{
    newStrings.Add(myStringBuilder.ToString(i, Math.Min(chunkSize, myStringBuilder.Length - i)));
}
```

If you wanted `StringBuilder` lengths then you can use `Append` on a new `StringBuilder` to get that (only in .NET 5.0):

```cs
const int chunkSize = 1000;
var newStrings = new List<StringBuilder>();
for (var i = 0; i < myStringBuilder.Length; i += chunkSize)
{
    newStrings.Add(new StringBuilder(chunkSize).Append(myStringBuilder, i, Math.Min(chunkSize, myStringBuilder.Length - i)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the input string and repeatedly take 1000-length substrings:

```
string input = "some string with 5000+ characters in it";
var list = new List<string>();
int i = 0;
while (i < input.Length) {
    int subLength = Math.Min(input.Length - i, 1000);
    string item = input.Substring(i, subLength);
    list.Add(item);
    i += 1000;
}
```

The output `list` should have some number of 1000 character strings, with the final entry possibly having fewer than 1000 characters, in the event that the original length be not a perfect multiple of 1000.

Comment: Thank you but i am getting error if string is less than 5000 characters

Comment: @GiorgosPanagiotidis Fixed, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.copyto?view=net-5.0#System_Text_StringBuilder_CopyTo_System_Int32_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_) method of StringBuilder class which copies the characters from a specified segment of the instance to a specified segment of a destination array.

Here is a simple code example how you can divide StringBuilder content into some strings:

```
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("12345678");
        // length of strings
        int length = 2;
        char[] destination = new char[length];
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= stringBuilder.Length - length; i += length)
        {
            stringBuilder.CopyTo(i, destination, 0, length);
            strings.Add(new string(destination));
        }
```

Comment: Your code does not correctly print the final chunk should it have a length less than 2 (which is actually the case you gave).

Comment: You are right. This sample code requires that a StringBuilder content should be a multiple of the single string length. Otherwise, the last chunk will not be copied.